# How do I generate FTL code reading text?

Tags: java, freemarker, filereader

### This is my FTL code which I want to generate reading some text input

```
<#include "BuiltInFunctions">
     @Rule (name = "${SOPName}_ErrorCheckParameters")
    <#assign _oppPreCondition>
      <@getOppositePrecondition/><#t>
      </#assign>
      if (${_oppPreCondition})
      {
        (Log (Insufficient parameters or values.))
        (Eject)
      }

      <#assign _USEPRECONDITION = "true">
    <#assign _preCondition>
       <@getPrecondition/><#t>
      </#assign>
    <#-- For loop for Parents -->
    <#if this.parents??>
    <#list this.parents as parent>
      <#if parent_index != 0>
      <#-- Insert a blank line -->
      </#if>
      <#if (getEntityOperatorCall(parent,"Check"))??>
    <#assign _operatorCall = getEntityOperatorCall(parent,"Check")>
    <#if _operatorCall??>
    <#if getReturnAndOutputSuccess("parentCheck_return","parentCheck_output")??>
    <#assign _successpredicate=getReturnAndOutputSuccess("parentCheck_return","parentCheck_output")>
    </#if>
     @Rule (name = "${SOPName}_Check${parent.name}")
      if (<#if _USEPRECONDITION = "true">${_preCondition} <#assign _USEPRECONDITION = "false"><#else>${_successpredicate}</#if>)
      {
        (parentCheck_return, parentCheck_output) = ${_operatorCall}
        (Log (${_operatorCall} output = ${"$"}{parentCheck_output}))
        (Log ((${_operatorCall} return = ${"$"}{parentCheck_return}))
      }
    <#if getReturnAndOutputFailure("parentCheck_return","parentCheck_output")??>
    <#assign _failurepredicate=getReturnAndOutputFailure("parentCheck_return","parentCheck_output")>
    </#if>
    @Rule (name = "${SOPName}_ErrorCheck${parent.name}")
        if(${_failurepredicate})
        {
            (Eject)
        }
      <#--<@getRules sopname=_rulename returnval="parentCheck_return" outputval="parentCheck_output"/><#t>-->

      </#if>
      </#if>
    </#list>
    </#if>

    <#if (getEntityOperatorCall(this,"Check"))??>
    <#assign _selfCheck = getEntityOperatorCall(this,"Check")>
    <#if _selfCheck??>
     @Rule (name = "${SOPName}_${this.operators["Check"].name}")
       if (<#if _USEPRECONDITION = "true">${_preCondition} <#assign _USEPRECONDITION = "false"><#else>${_successpredicate}</#if>)
      {
        (selfCheck_return, selfCheck_output) = ${_selfCheck}
        (Log (${_selfCheck} output = ${"$"}{selfCheck_output}))
        (Log (${_selfCheck} return = ${"$"}{selfCheck_return}))
      }
     <#if getReturnAndOutputSuccess("selfCheck_return","selfCheck_output")??>
    <#assign _successpredicate=getReturnAndOutputSuccess("selfCheck_return","selfCheck_output")>
    </#if>
    <#if getReturnAndOutputFailure("selfCheck_return","selfCheck_output")??>
    <#assign _failurepredicate=getReturnAndOutputFailure("selfCheck_return","selfCheck_output")>
    </#if>
    @Rule (name = "${SOPName}_ErrorCheck${this.name}")
        if(${_failurepredicate})
        {
            (Eject)
        }
    <#--  <@getRules sopname=_rulename returnval="selfCheck_return" outputval="selfCheck_output"/><#t> -->

    </#if>
    </#if>
    <#if (getEntityOperatorCall(this,Verb))??>
    <#assign _mainTask = getEntityOperatorCall(this,Verb)>
    <#if _mainTask??>
    <#if _selfCheck??>
      @Rule (name = "${SOPName}_${this.operators[Verb].name}")
      if (${_failurepredicate})
      {
        (mainTask_return, mainTask_output) = ${_mainTask}
        (Log (${_mainTask} output = ${"$"}{mainTask_output}))
        (Log (${_mainTask} return = ${"$"}{mainTask_return}))
      }

    <#else>
    @Rule (name = "${SOPName}_${this.operators[Verb].name}")
     if (<#if _USEPRECONDITION = "true">${_preCondition} <#assign _USEPRECONDITION = "false"><#else>${_successpredicate}</#if>)
      {
        (mainTask_return, mainTask_output) = ${_mainTask}
        (Log (${_mainTask} output = ${"$"}{mainTask_output}))
        (Log (${_mainTask} return = ${"$"}{mainTask_return}))
      }

    </#if>
    <#if getReturnAndOutputSuccess("mainTask_return","mainTask_output")??>
    <#assign _successpredicate=getReturnAndOutputSuccess("mainTask_return","mainTask_output")>
    </#if>
    <#if getReturnAndOutputFailure("mainTask_return","mainTask_output")??>
    <#assign _failurepredicate=getReturnAndOutputFailure("mainTask_return","mainTask_output")>
    </#if>
    @Rule (name = "${SOPName}_Error${this.operators[Verb].name}")
        if(${_failurepredicate})
        {
            (Eject)
        }
    <#--  <@getRules sopname=_rulename returnval="mainTask_return" outputval="mainTask_output"/><#t>-->

       @Rule (name = "${SOPName}_Success${this.operators[Verb].name}")
      if (${_successpredicate})
      {
        (Log (${Verb} ${this.name} resulted in success ))
        (Resolve)
      }

    </#if>
    </#if>
```

---

```
##########################################################
 @Rule (name = "SetEntityB_ErrorCheckParameters")
  if ()
  {
    (Log (Insufficient parameters or values.))
    (Eject)
  }

 @Rule (name = "SetEntityB_CheckB")
  if ( )
  {
    (parentCheck_return, parentCheck_output) = A:CheckEntityB()
    (Log (A:CheckEntityB() output = ${parentCheck_output}))
    (Log ((A:CheckEntityB() return = ${parentCheck_return}))
  }
@Rule (name = "SetEntityB_ErrorCheckB")
    if(parentCheck_return != 0)
    {
        (Eject)
    }


@Rule (name = "SetEntityB_SetattrB")
 if (parentCheck_return = 0)
  {
    (mainTask_return, mainTask_output) = A:SetattrB()
    (Log (A:SetattrB() output = ${mainTask_output}))
    (Log (A:SetattrB() return = ${mainTask_return}))
  }

@Rule (name = "SetEntityB_ErrorSetattrB")
    if(mainTask_return != 0)
    {
        (Eject)
    }

   @Rule (name = "SetEntityB_SuccessSetattrB")
  if (mainTask_return = 0)
  {
    (Log (Set attrB resulted in success ))
    (Resolve)
  }
```

The ftl code generates above shown text as an output. But if I  want to do it in a reverse way. Reading text, the FTL code should get generated. how that is done?

#

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing that you are asking about. This is an one way proccess. I don't even see how would that be possible "mathematically".

Comment: there's no need to generate exact code as it is. Even i know it would be impossible to do so. Bt is there any way, we can generate some template code reading text input.and then we would be able to modify it the way we want.

Comment: I don't know about such utility.